# sensors Information about degree of adapter

Tags: linux, fan, sensors

In this Image (output of `sensors`):

[image]

On the top, just below radeon-pci-0100, it says `temperature +511 Deg C`, does this really mean 511, will this not blow up my laptop?

Comment: Don't you mean the `sensors` command? How do you get `i8kfan` to print the data you show?

Comment: ahhh, yes, you right, i edited the title

Answer (score 1):

Your computer does seem to be overheating, you are past the high and close to the critical values for some of your cores. You should try cleaning it out or [switching governors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64304/22222).

Now, as for the 511 degrees I am pretty sure that if your computer were actually *that* hot you would know it, that is more than twice as hot as an oven. Unless you can fry eggs on your keyboard this is most likely a malfunctioning sensor somewhere.

So, no, the 511 is probably not real but you nevertheless probably have a serious heating problem.